# Reading a portion of a large xlsx file with python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large .xlsx file with 1 million rows. I don't want to open the whole file in one go. I was wondering if I can read a chunk of the file, process it and then read the next chunk? (I prefer to use pandas for it.)

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** 2019-09-05

The `chunksize` parameter has been deprecated as it wasn't used by `pd.read_excel()`, because of the nature of XLSX file format, which will be read up into memory as a whole during parsing.

There are more details about that in [this great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47455961/5741205)...

---

**OLD answer:**

you can use [read_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) method:

```
chunksize = 10**5
for chunk in pd.read_excel(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    # process `chunk` DF
```

if your excel file has multiple sheets, take a look at [bpachev's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38623545/5741205) solution

Comment: I get with pandas v0.19.2: `NotImplementedError: chunksize keyword of read_excel is not implemented`

Comment: Same for pandas `0.20.2`

Comment: @iipr, [it was removed in Pandas 0.17.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45346340/5741205)

Comment: Oh I see. @MaxU Is there another alternative for reading an Excel using chunking?

Comment: @iipr, i’ll try to implement it, but I’m not sure it will be fast. Why do you need it? Does your data set fit in memory?

Comment: @MaxU thank you for your help. Ideally it should be an argument of `pd.read_excel` like for `pd.read_csv` (unless I'm missing something, which could be the case). My current dataset does fit in memory, but because I'm currently using a pc with 32GB, which doesn't always happen. I want to use it to move data contained in Excels to HDFs.

Comment: @iipr, it's not that easy, as both standard engines Pandas is using - `xlrd` and `openpyxl` are reading the whole file in memory first. So I think you would need to convert it to CSV file first and then you can read it in chunks...

Comment: @MaxU that is exactly what I tried yesterday: save the Excel as CSV and then read it. In general, Excels will not be too big as for to not fit in memory, so its fine I guess. The only thing is to be careful with the conversion to avoid data leaks/mistakes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Pandas supports chunked reading. You would go about reading an excel file like so.

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile("myfile.xlsx")
for sheet_name in xl.sheet_names:
  reader = xl.parse(sheet_name, chunksize=1000):
  for chunk in reader:
    #parse chunk here
```

Comment: I get with pandas v0.19.2: `NotImplementedError: chunksize keyword of read_excel is not implemented`

Comment: Same for pandas `0.20.2`

Comment: You are suggesting O[N^2) complexity to read files ....