# chunksize keyword of read_excel is not implemented

Tags: python, pandas

In version 0.16.1 the `chunksize` argument was available.

See: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.1/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html

But in latest version it's not available.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html

What was the reason that it was removed?

Also, how should I process excel file by chunks in latest version?

I used to do below:

```
import pandas as pd

excel = pd.ExcelFile("test.xlsx")

for sheet in excel.sheet_names:
    reader = excel.parse(sheet, chunksize=1000)
    for chunk in reader:
        # process chunk
```

Comment: It was unsupported and removed in [`0.17.0`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0170-api-breaking-other) so it'll raise an unsupportedError now. See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/11198 and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8011. As it uses `xlrd` this looks like it's loading the entire worksheet into memory and so far `chunksize` has not been added back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345506/chunksize-keyword-of-read-excel-is-not-implemented#comment77652595_45345506) explained in the comment, this feature was removed in 0.17.0. [Chris](https://github.com/chris-b1) gave below reason for the same in the comment:

> there's no super-compelling reason; the main idea was to match up with
>   api of to_excel, i.e. the "ExcelFileWrapper" (ExcelFile, ExcelWriter)
>   doesn't have any pandas-specific functionality, instead you pass it
>   into the io functions (read_excel, to_excel).
>
> I did update the docs to cover that specific example. edit: although
>   it may be hard to see in the diff - rendered below.

Source: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/11198

I still wonder if there's any alternate way to read excel in chunks?

Comment: has anyone figured out if there is a fast way to do this?