# how to read the text file read in data frame with split function?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, file-handling

I have this data set in an Excel file. I want to keep the data which have only length 6 and delete rest and export it in the split of single values stored in a separate column.

Please tell me if we have any function to split the *numeric values*  in the file to read it and split

[image]

Comment: what did you get when you read in the file?

Comment: It’s big data like 9.8 million error related to memory so before reading to dataframe I want to grab only values which have 6 digits in the row and drop other

Comment: IIUC, your data is in an excel file, so maybe openpyxl can help. You iterate through the rows and keep only those with length 6. hopefully this post here can guide you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35823835/reading-excel-file-is-magnitudes-slower-using-openpyxl-compared-to-xlrd

Answer (score 2):

From your shared data it seems it has spaces between numbers so they will already be in `str`

you can try below code:

your `df` looks like this:

```
    a
0   11
1   2
2   3 2 4 
3   5
4   1
5   6
6   1 1
7   6
8   6 7 7 7 6 6 8 8 8
9   6 8 7 9 5 2 1 44 6 55
10  6 8 7 9 5 2 1 44 6 55 4 4 4 4
```

filter rows with `len` equal to 6

```
df=df[df['a'].str.len()==6]
```

then split them using `split()` method like this

```
df['a'].str.split(" ", expand = True)
```

output:

```
    0   1   2   3
2   3   2   4
```

EDIT:

for having trouble with memory while reading a large file you can refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557074/memory-error-when-using-pandas-read-csv) post 
OR read the file in chunks and append/save the output in new file

```
reader = pd.read_csv(filePath,chunksize=1000000,low_memory=False,header=0)
```

Comment: chunksize keyword of read_excel is not implemented what is the issue now>

Comment: refer to this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345506/chunksize-keyword-of-read-excel-is-not-implemented