# Loading Excel file chunk by chunk with Python instead of loading full file into memory

Tags: python, excel, file, xlsx

I want to read just 10 lines from Excel files (xlsx) without loading the whole file at once, as it can't be done on one of my machines (low memory).

I tried using

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
def open_file(path):
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(path)
    reader = xl.parse(chunksize=1000)
    for chunk in reader:
        print(chunk)
```

It seems like the file is loaded first then divided into parts.

How to read only first lines?

Comment: you're clearly using pandas, but haven't specified it - are you showing the full code?

Comment: although not strictly adhering to pandas, my advise would be to use SFrame which automatically does out of core computation and is fast. Install using `pip install --U sframe`

Comment: Barnabus there is no need for showing more code. I just want to load ONLY n rows.
Edit:
@VivekKalyanarangan Thanks for answer. I will check it out.

Comment: `xslx` is a zip file. It doesn't make it easier to read just a few lines.Could you read a  CSV file instead?

Comment: I'd love to. Unfortunately I can't.

Comment: Have you tried [openpyxl's read-only mode](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the nature of `xlsx` files (which are essentially a bunch of `xml` files zipped together) you can't poke the file at an arbitrary byte and hope for it to be the beginning of Nth row of the table in the sheet you are interested in.

The best you can do is use [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) with the `skiprows` (skips rows from the top of the file) and `skip_footer` (skips rows from the bottom) arguments. This however will load the whole file to memory first and then parse the required rows only.

```
# if the file contains 300 rows, this will read the middle 100
df = pd.read_excel('/path/excel.xlsx', skiprows=100, skip_footer=100,
                   names=['col_a', 'col_b'])
```

Note that you have to set the headers manually with the `names` argument otherwise the column names will be the last skipped row.

If you wish to use `csv` instead then it is a straightforward task since `csv` files are plain-text files.

**But**, and it's a big *but*, if you are really desperate you can extract the relevant sheet's `xml` file from the `xlsx` archive and parse that. It's not going to be an easy task though.

An example `xml` file that represents a sheet with a single 2 X 3 table. The `<v>` tags represent the cells' value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="x14ac" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac">
    <dimension ref="A1:B3"/>
    <sheetViews>
        <sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0">
            <selection activeCell="C10" sqref="C10"/>
        </sheetView>
    </sheetViews>
    <sheetFormatPr defaultColWidth="11" defaultRowHeight="14.25" x14ac:dyDescent="0.2"/>
    <sheetData>
        <row r="1" spans="1:2" ht="15.75" x14ac:dyDescent="0.2">
            <c r="A1" t="s">
                <v>1</v>
            </c><c r="B1" s="1" t="s">
                <v>0</v>
            </c>
        </row>
        <row r="2" spans="1:2" ht="15" x14ac:dyDescent="0.2">
            <c r="A2" s="2">
                <v>1</v>
            </c><c r="B2" s="2">
                <v>4</v>
            </c>
        </row>
        <row r="3" spans="1:2" ht="15" x14ac:dyDescent="0.2">
            <c r="A3" s="2">
                <v>2</v>
            </c><c r="B3" s="2">
                <v>5</v>
            </c>
        </row>
    </sheetData>
    <pageMargins left="0.75" right="0.75" top="1" bottom="1" header="0.5" footer="0.5"/>
</worksheet>
```

Comment: Problem is, that it loads whole file, then splits it to chunks. Thanks for answer, but it also is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Kornel See my updated answer, I've added some info.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Nice bunch of information worth knowing. I will mark this as an answer to my question.

Comment: @DeepSpace How could you decode the xlsx file ? It seems like its binary

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan I didn't decode anything. I merely extracted the relevant sheet's XML file from the XLSX file, which, as explained in my answer, is "just" a fancy archive file. Try to open one with 7zip for example

Comment: When `t="s"` as in the first row, the value is a zero based index into a shared string table. That table can be found in `xl/sharedStrings.xml`.