# How to read a large .XLS file in chunks without loading it into RAM at once

Tags: python, django, parsing, xls, chunking

I try to parse different kinds of very large Excel Files (.csv, .xlsx, .xls)

### Working (.csv/.xlsx) flows

**.csv** is chunkable by using `pandas.read_csv(file, chunksize=chunksize)`

**.xlsx** is chunkable by unzipping it and parsing inner .xml files using `lxml.etree.iterparse(zip_file.open('xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml'))` and `lxml.etree.iterparse(zip_file.open('xl/sharedStrings.xml'))`, performing additional operations afterwards.

### Not working (.xls) flow

**.xls** I can't find any info on how to split this file in chunks!

Details: My file has a type of Django's `TemporaryUploadedFile`. I get it from `request.data['file']` on `PUT` request.

I get a path of the file like `request.data['file'].temporary_file_path()`. This is '/tmp/tmpu73gux4m.upload'. (I'm not sure what the *****.upload file is. I guess it's some kind of HTTP file encoding)

When I try to read it:

```
file.open()
content = file.read()
```

the `content` looks like a bytes string `b'\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1\x1a\xe1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...etc.`

### Question

1. Are there any means of encoding and parsing this bytes string?
2. Ideally, I would want to read .xls row by row without loading the whole file into RAM at once. Are there any means of doing it?

Comment: can't you convert file into csv and then use pandas .

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455562/loading-excel-file-chunk-by-chunk-with-python-instead-of-loading-full-file-into.

Comment: @Piyush S. Wanare no, I can't convert it. Thousands of customers send me `.xls` files. There is no option to inform them about converting their files to `.csv`. Of course, it would be the best option for me but it's impossible.

Comment: @Piyush S. Wanare the link you applied contains the info about `.xlsx` only. I need info about `.xls`