# Efficiently extract sheet names, and column names from large .xlsx with Python3

Tags: excel, python-3.x, performance, pandas, memory

What are the Python3 options to efficiently (performance and memory) extract sheet names and for a given sheet, and also column names from a very large .xlsx file?

I've tried using pandas:

For sheet names using `pd.ExcelFile`:

```
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    return xl.sheet_names
```

For column names using `pd.ExcelFile`:

```
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    df = xl.parse(sheetname, nrows=2, **kwargs)
    df.columns
```

For column names using `pd.read_excel` with and without `nrows` (>v23):

```
    df = pd.read_excel(io=filename, sheet_name=sheetname, nrows=2)
    df.columns
```

However, both `pd.ExcelFile` and and `pd.read_excel` seem to read the entire .xlsx in memory and are therefore slow.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't have anything handy to test, but how does `dfs = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None, nrows=0)` perform? You should get a dictionary with sheet names as keys and an empty DataFrame as its values...

Answer (score 4):

Here is the easiest way I can share with you:

```
# read the sheet file
import pandas as pd
my_sheets = pd.ExcelFile('sheet_filename.xlsx')
my_sheets.sheet_names
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623368/reading-a-portion-of-a-large-xlsx-file-with-python), reading excel files in chunks is not supported ([see this issue on github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8011)), and using `nrows` will always read all the file into memory first.

Possible solutions:

- Convert the sheet to csv, and read that in chunks.
- Use something other than pandas. See [this page](http://www.python-excel.org/) for a list of alternative libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would help the need

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook(filename, read_only=True)

data = {}   #for storing the value of sheet with their respective columns

for sheet in worksheets:
    for value in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1, values_only=True):
        data[sheet.title] = value #value would be a tuple with headings of each column
```

Answer (score 0):

This program lists all the sheets in the excel. 
Pandas is used here.

```
import pandas as pd
with pd.ExcelFile('yourfile.xlsx') as xlsx :
    sh=xlsx.sheet_names
print("This workbook has the following sheets : ",sh)
```